# ajQuery - Start slideshow on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and would like to start a slideshow after a link is clicked instead of after the page is loaded. How to do that?

```
>   <script type="text/javascript">  
> jQuery(document).ready(function($){ $("a[rel^='id']").prettyPhoto({
>                 theme: 'pp_default',slideshow:5000, autoplay_slideshow:true});
>         });
>     </script>
```

I would like to start it like this:

```
<a href="javascript:startSlideshow()">Start Slideshow</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ID for tag "A":

```
<a href="javascript:" id="slide">Start Slideshow</a>

<script type="text/javascript">  
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#slide').click(function(){
    $("a[rel^='id']").prettyPhoto({
               theme: 'pp_default',slideshow:5000, autoplay_slideshow:true});
    });
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<a href="javascript:" id="slide">Start Slideshow</a>

<script type="text/javascript">  
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#slide').click(function(){
        $("a[rel^='id']").click();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but for some reason nothing happends after clicking the link. The function receives a call but nothing comes after that. Anything I am missing?

Comment: Could you try to use some css class instead of a[rel^='id']? $(".imagelist").prettyPhoto(...);

Comment: I looked through the manual. I found two parameters there. Did you try to use autoplay:false and autoplay_slideshow: false?

Comment: I guess my problem is a little bit more complex. I want to start the **prettyPhoto** slideshow from a text link instead of oneof the images from the gallery. This is the website I downloaded it from: http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#!prettyPhoto[pp_gal2]/0/ - Is anybody able to find out how to do it?

Comment: This is the gallery code: `<a href="images/fullscreen/1.jpg" rel="id[pp_gal]" title="You can add caption to pictures."><img src="images/thumbnails/t_1.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="Red round shape" /></a>`

Comment: Ok. Lets try to set autoplay:false and autoplay_slideshow: false. And change the code like in my post update.